# Correct way to make element with horizontal scroll

Tags: css

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/WsYw8/ 
Demo of what im talking about : http://netkoder.dk/test/test0251.html

**HTML**

```
<div class="spotlysholderholder baggrundlinear1 bordertype1 borderradius5px">

   <div class="spotlysholderholderb" style="width: 3200px;">
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <a href="/" class="spotlysholder background_color_2 fontsize_xsmall fontfamily_1 bordertype1 borderradius5px"><img src="test0251_filer/billed0001.png" alt="Notepad++" class="spotlysbillede"><span class="">NOTEPAD++</span>er et tekstredigeringsprogram du kan bruge til at skrive dine koder</a>
      <div class="clearboth"></div>
   </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .spotlysholderholder {
      overflow-x: auto;
   }

   .spotlysholderholderb {
      padding: 4px;
      margin: 0 auto;
   /*   width: 800px;*/
   }

   .spotlysholderholderb a,
   .spotlysholderholderb a:visited,
   .spotlysholderholderb a:active {
      color: #222;
   }

   .spotlysholder {
      text-align: center;
      width: 180px;
      float: left;
      margin: 4px;
      padding: 5px;
      text-decoration: none;

      /* for at undgå at langeordudenmellem ikke går ud over kanten */
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
   }

   .spotlysholder:hover {
      background: #ccc;
      text-decoration: underline;
      border-color: black;
   }

   .spotlyoverskrift {
      display: block;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: maroon;
   }

   .spotlysbillede {
      margin: 5px auto;
      vertical-align: bottom;
   }

   .baggrundlinear1 {
      background-color: #445263; /* fallback */
      box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), inset -2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 -2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 2px 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
   }


   .bordertype1 {
      border: 1px solid #7c7c7c; /* fallback farve når rgba ikke virker */
      border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
   }

   .background_color_2 {
      background-color: #ddd; /* fallback */
   }

   .borderradius5px {
      border-radius: 5px;
   }

   .spotlysbillede {
      margin: 5px auto;
      vertical-align: bottom;
   }

   .clearboth {
      clear: both;
   }
```

I have a scrolling element with 16 boxes.

Each box are 200 pixels wide including padding.

In order to get them all on the same line i make the parent container elemenet 16 * 200 pixel wide. If there are 16 boxes i make it 3200px wide.

I have 2 problems.

1 : How can i avoid setting the width of the parent container element and still have all the boxes on the same line ?

2 : When i use the browser to zoom out, the last box jump down making 2 lines.

Comment: Are you using any server-side script to add random number of boxed to the division?

Comment: Yes i want to be able to change the number of boxes without having to set the width. Right now i calculate the width with X * 200 serverside but i would like not to do that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution to have all boxes lined up without knowledge about the overall wide is using `display: inline-block` in conjunction with `white-space: nowrap;` instead of *floating* elements. This won't break while zooming. Using the `<body>`-element is just an example. You could also use a wrapper like `<div class="spotlysholderholderb">` (to stick to your example) with the same styles applied, when only a part of your page should be scrollable horizontally.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="">
    <p>Box 1</p>
</div>

<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="">
    <p>Box 2</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/t2xvG/)

[Try before (centered horizontally)](http://jsfiddle.net/2V7VR/)

Comment: Cool, just what i was looking for. I have been avoiding display: inline-block for my website because i read it was not supported so much. But seems to be good support now. So i will try it.

Comment: When i add .spotlysholder { vertical-align: top; } internet explorer shows a vertical scrollbar. Whats going on here ? bottom and middle dont show vertical scrollbar.

Comment: I would also like to keep the boxes in the middle when there is for example only 4 boxes and no horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @scootergrisen Simply use `text-align: center;` on the wrapper, to center them. I've added a demo to the question to demonstrate it. Maybe you have some overflow in IE, did you set the line height to 0? Did you take care of all margins, padding and borders?

Comment: Got the text-align: center; to work now but still can't the vertical scrollbar away in internet explorer. Might be a browser bug. Try this in both firefox and IE and notice the red background is different : http://jsfiddle.net/PjF6y/

Answer (score 0):

a JSfiddle would have been more helpfull, still try this :

**1** add this to your css   `.spotlysholderholderb > a {display:block;float:left}`

**2** Place `<div class="clearboth"></div>` outside `spotlysholderholderb` div class.

let me know if it helps!! :)

Comment: jsfiddle dont want to be my friend right not. nothing happens when i click save. I cant get it to be better with your code. The boxes wraps on 2 or more linies if i remove the 3200 width.

Comment: added fiddle for you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

For random number of boxes what i would do is:

1->count the number of boxes.store them in textfield like:

`<textarea id="count" style="visibility:hidden;">$count</textarea>`

2->Write Jquery at the end of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cnt=parseInt(count.value);
    var wid=cnt*200;
    $("#parent_div").css({ width:''+wid+'px'});
});
```

Comment: I dont want to use javascript/jquery for this. I would like the most clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:As requested without javascript/JQuery.**

For random number of boxes what i would do is:

1->count the number of boxes $count.

2->For PHP

```
$wid=$count*200;

Echo "<div id='parent_div' style='width:".$wid.";'>";
any loop{
Echo "<div id='boxes'><div>";
}
Echo "</div>";
```